# Sending a push notification to a user in the database

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement push notification using Firebase Cloud Messaging but it seems as if you have to register the device to receive push notifications. I am trying to make it so when there is action in the database, such as an inbox reply, send a push notification to the user who received the message.

Is there a way to send the push notification with Firebase to a particular user, not a particular device?

Comment: you send your registration token to your server then when you want to send a push message to that user you push it to their registration token

Answer (score 3):

You don't send push notifications to a user, you send them to a device.

Somewhere in your code (maybe when your user signs up/ logs in to your app), you have to execute the code to get a GCM registration token. This token is unique to your Android app and that specific Android device.

With that token, you can send push notifications to that device using any method you want (from an app, from a website, etc. If you have a GCM reg token you can even send pushes from this handy website: http://1-dot-sigma-freedom-752.appspot.com/).

It is now your responsibility to keep a database of your users and their GCM registration tokens. When a user wants to send a push to another user, you would find the corresponding registration token in your database and then execute the code to send them the push using that token.

Answer (score 0):

FCM provides several ways for you to send notifications to your users. You can send messages directly to devices via an Instance ID token, you can send messages to a topic that your user has subscribed to, and you can also send messages to groups of users eg: country/language etc.

Have a look at this [sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging) which demonstrates sending to a device and topic. Also have a look at the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) for more details on sending and receiving messages.