# Best and easiest way to create a push notification

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, mongoose

I'm using nodejs as server, mongodb as database, mongoose as library and  react native as client side .
I need to send a notification to a specifique user from the database .
How can this be resolved?

Comment: Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37442434/9890122

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method which I used so far is using firebase's real-time DB. I also had the same stack as you. However, I used Firebase and made my life easier.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but for those coming here and using RealmDB/MongoDB, you can use [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification).

You have to create a new [Firebase account](https://console.firebase.google.com/) and connect it with [push notifications](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/services/send-mobile-push-notifications/) in your Realm console.

It's all a bit tricky, but when your done with that, you will end up with a code that will look like this in your index.js:

```js
import PushNotificationIOS from '@react-native-community/push-notification-ios';
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';

PushNotification.configure({
  onRegister: function (token) {
    console.log('TOKEN:', token);
  },

  onNotification: function (notification) {
    console.log('NOTIFICATION:', notification);
    notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
  },

  onAction: function (notification) {
    console.log('ACTION:', notification.action);
    console.log('NOTIFICATION:', notification);
  },

  onRegistrationError: function (err) {
    console.error(err.message, err);
  },

  permissions: {
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  },
  popInitialNotification: true,
  requestPermissions: true,
});

PushNotification.subscribeToTopic('topic-id-in-realm-console');
```

The most important part to make it works with Realm is this line:

```js
PushNotification.subscribeToTopic('topic-id-in-realm-console');
```

You'll have to add the same topic name in your new notification in Realm:

[image]

It's working now on Android (not tested yet on IOS):

[image: Notification on client]

To customise your notification you'll have to use [rules and functions](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/services/push-notifications/), but I'm still working on it and don't now yet how to do it.

Hope this will help some lost people like me.